# UITableView disable swipe to delete for particular cells swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to disable swipe to delete action for some particular cells in tableview. but i could not be find a good solution in swift. I don't want that left side minus sign on cell when overriding  "tableView.isEditing = true" method.Here is my code. below code is not disabling swipe to the cell with statusId "12". Hope you understand my problem.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifier", for: indexPath) as! TableViewDateCell
    cell.titleStatus.text = mainList[indexPath.row].statusName
    //tableView.isEditing = true
    //disable swipe to delete for cell with statusId == "12"
    if mainList[indexPath.row].statusId == "12" {
         //tableView.isEditing = false
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.gray
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    }
 }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You might customize the `UITableViewDelegate`'s function `editingStyleForRowAt`, especially returning `UITableViewCellEditingStyle.none` when you don't need the swipe, something like:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle
{
   if mainList[indexPath.row].statusId == "12" {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.none
    } else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this table view delegate method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

}
```

[Documentation tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614900-tableview?language=objc)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for posting this question and the answers above.

On an expansion of the answers, I had a default row that should never be deleted, so I set a tag on that particular cell and then *at first* used this method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.tag == 100 {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

**HOWEVER** - This caused the following warning in Debugger -

> Attempted to call -cellForRowAtIndexPath: on the table view while it
>   was in the process of updating its visible cells, which is not
>   allowed.

So, as other commentators have said, use this method below:

**Swift 5.0**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.tag == 100 {
        return UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.none
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! I was facing the same error table view updating but now editingStyleForRowAt works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i was trying to disable/enable the delete feature when i edit the myTableview.
this is my solution:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle
{
    if !myTableView.isEditing {
        return UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.none
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Swift 4.2 inside viewDidLoad just set your table value to...

```
myTableView.isEditing = false
```